# Latex - Blank table of contents with unnumbered section

Tags: latex, tex

When trying to create a table of contents with an unnumbered section, I get an empty table of contents, even after multiple repeated compilations.

When I use a numbered section, the table of contents works fine.

An example (complete Latex document) is shown below (I was trying to keep it as simple as possible):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section*{Testsection} %Works when section* is replaced with section
 Test
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Entries of starred versions of sectional units can be inserted in the ToC using

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{<type>}{<content>}
```

where `<type>` is `section`, or `subsection`, or... Here is a minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A numbered section}
\section*{An unnumbered section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Testsection}
\section{Another numbered section}
\section*{Another unnumbered section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{}Another unnumbered section}
\end{document}
```

For alignment purposes, you may be interested in adding a `\protect`ed `\numberline` to the ToC entry.